# Multiple conflicting htaccess RewriteRules

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to have both people's profiles at example.com/Sara and a few special pages like example.com/home and /account.

How do I make both of my RewriteRules work?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./people.php?s=$1
RewriteRule ^home ./home.php
```

Thanks!

Edit:

Figured it out...!

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./people.php?s=$1
```

Comment: post your answer as an answer, and not an amendment to the question ... this way you can close the question as answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...!

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./people.php?s=$1
```