# Htaccess conflicts

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to do some rewrites with my .htaccess file

***All  I am trying to do is rewrite the url:*** 

www.example.com/book.php?course=#WHATEVERSLUG

**to**

www.example.com/course/#WHATEVERSLUG

WHICH I HAVE SUCCESSFULLY BEEN USING THE CODE BELOW FOR A WHILE NOW WITH NO ERRORS

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^course\/([^/\.]+)/?$ book.php?course=$1 [L]
```

Then, I tried adding another rewrite mod, below:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

to shorten my urls by removing the .php extensions, and remove the traling slashes and it appears that they do not mix well for some reason. I am not very good with .Htaccess, so any help will be possitive.

Or if someone has another suggestion to rewrite:

www.example.com/book.php?course=#WHATEVERSLUG

**to**

www.example.com/course/#WHATEVERSLUG

And

Rewrite .php files to remove extenstions and traling slashes..

it'd be so greately appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to rewrite all php files to not have .php? e.g. yoursite.com/about which would forward to about.php internally?

Comment: yes, but if there is way to rewrite a single file, and than i could duplicate it and change it for whatever file i wanted to do it for, that would work even cooler, but i just want to get it working together

Answer (score 0):

## Figured it out!:

**w/ a little a help from:** [Multiple conflicting htaccess RewriteRules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729166/multiple-conflicting-htaccess-rewriterules?rq=1)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^course\/([^/\.]+)/?$ ./book.php?course=$1
```